# NetBeans building failure | make Error 1

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, makefile, sfml

I get the following errors while building my project (game with C++/SFML):

```
cd '/home/osboxes/NetBeansProjects/Prueba'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/osboxes/NetBeansProjects/Prueba'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/prueba
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/osboxes/NetBeansProjects/Prueba'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/prueba build/Debug/GNU-Linux/AABBCollidable.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/AABBCollisionDetector.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/AnimatedSprite.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/Animation.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/ConvexCollidable.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/ConvexCollisionDetector.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/ConvexShape.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/Director.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/Entry.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/Event.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/EventManager.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/FileLogger.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/GuiElement.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/GuiSystem.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/Label.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/LabelButton.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/ResourceManager.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/State.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:79: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/prueba' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/prueba] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/osboxes/NetBeansProjects/Prueba'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:76: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/osboxes/NetBeansProjects/Prueba'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

I have installed NetBeans IDE 8.1 with SFML libraries. I tried to fix it by clearing cache from NetBeans and then restart IDE but still does the same errors.
My project was compiled with Standard C++ compiler (C++11 version).

Hope you could help me. Thanks by the way...

[image: Build Tools]

Comment: There's not enough info here for anyone to be able to help you...   You may want to turn on make's debugging (`man make`) to see what the recipe that's failing is, and go from there.

Comment: You haven't shown us the failing linker command or the error it generated. You've just shown us the "That didn't work. Goodbye"-epilogue. Post the complete build log instead.

Comment: Here it is the complete log @MikeKinghan

Comment: @danibeam Are you sure? Part of the log appears to be missing after `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':`

Comment: @MikeKinghan that it's what I get, if it was a way to show those paths completely...

Comment: What is the name of the C++ source file that contains the `main` function of your program?